# Is it possible to use Gorilla mux router with Google appengine standard environment?

Tags: google-app-engine, go, mux

Is there a way to get `appengine.Main()` to work with mux router? The following code compiles but does not match any routes.

```
func main() {
  r := mux.NewRouter()
  r.HandleFunc("/", indexHandler)
  http.Handle("/", r)
  appengine.Main()
}
```

Comment: Yes. The [router documentation](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/mux#Router) describes how to use the router on App Engine.

Answer (score 0):

The source of the problem was my `app.yaml`. I had

```
handlers:
  - url: /api/.*
    script: _go_app
```

Therefore, in order to match the routes properly, I had to update the paths in mux router to match the full path.

```
r.HandleFunc("/api/", indexHandler)
```